# GWT Dev mode with 2 modules

Tags: gwt, gwt-dev-mode

I have 2 maven projects ('A' and 'B'). Both have a gwt module. The gwt modul of the 'A' project inherits the gwt modul of the 'B' project. Everything works fine.

I use Eclipse and i have a launch configuration for the Dev mode. I set the parameters of the 'A' module in the launch config and start it. It works. If i change the code then i see the changes in the browser window. I mentioned that the A module inherits the B module, but if i change the code in the B module, this change won't appear in the browser (because the dev mode configured to A module). How can i configure the dev mode to see the changes of both modules in the browser?

Comment: should directly work, if you use Project B in the Buildpath of Project A (and not a compiled JAR)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the project B to the project A's Java Build Path as shown below.

Right Click on Project A's Properties -> Java Build Path -> Projects Tab -> Add.. Project B

[image]

Please have a look at below post for step by step description.

- [Multiple Projects and GWT](http://svenbuschbeck.net/wordpress/2012/04/multiple-projects-and-gwt/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Braj. The site you linked was helpful. The key was the Step3. I created a source folder pointing to my B project. And i added this folder to the classpath in my dev mode launch configuration.